# Detect "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently" error using PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Im sending email through PHPMailer but sometimes the email addresses that I have are not valid email addresses so I see in my gmail account an email with the error "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently".
I want to catch this error using PHPMailer and to notify the user about this error.
When Im trying to send the email PHPMailer does not catch this error, I guess that its some config issue. This is my code:

```
if(empty($email) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                    return BasicServer::serverResponse(Errors::NOT_VALID_PASSWORD_EMAIL_RESTORE, "User email is not valid");


       $mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mailer->isSMTP();

        try {

            $mailer->CharSet        = 'UTF-8';
            $mailer->FromName       = "soInFit";
            $mailer->Host           = "xxxxxx"; // SMTP server
            debug information (for testing)
            $mailer->SMTPAuth       = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            $mailer->SMTPSecure     = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier     
            $mailer->Host           = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
            $mailer->Port           = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
            $mailer->Username       = "xxxxxx";  // GMAIL username
            $mailer->Password       = 'xxxxx';            // GMAIL password
            $mailer->Subject        = $subject;
            $mailer->Body           = $message;
            $mailer->IsHTML(true); 

            $mailer->addAddress($email);
            if(!$mailer->Send())
                return BasicServer::serverResponse(Errors::UPDATE_ERROR, $mailer->ErrorInfo);

        } catch (phpmailerException $ex) {

            return BasicServer::serverResponse(Errors::UPDATE_ERROR, $ex->errorMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return BasicServer::serverResponse(Errors::UPDATE_ERROR, $e->errorMessage());
        }
```

Comment: This is not a "config issue" as you suspect. This is an issue you _can not_ "catch" within your script. Reason is that this error is raised in an asynchronous manner. The smtp server you use to send the mails accept the message from your client and queues it. At that time no error is raised. Only later, when the smtp server tries to deliver the email, and failed after to a configured period of time (4 days typical), only then the error is raised. That is however completely decoupled from your script run which is why you cannot detect it. You would need to implement an imap client for that.

Comment: Ok, Is there other way to verify mail addresses before sending them?
The user may send email and think that its fine when actually the email address is not valid

Comment: Sure there is. Apart from primitive tests with regular expressions or phps builtin value filter extension you can simply open a connection to the receiving smtp server and test if a mail to a certain address is accepted or not. You can do that independently from the actual sending of the message. Note that you have to connect direct, which causes issues for more complex setups like gray listing.

Comment: See my edit I do the regular expressions but what about emails like this: foo@foo.com, its valid for the regular expressions but there is no email address like this.
How can I open the connection to smtp and checking the email? do you have any links for it:?

Comment: Be careful with the statement "there is no email address like this". You simply don't know that. The fact that a message from you gets rejected or is not accepted does _not_ mean that this address (which certainly does exist) is not in actual use.

Comment: About the connection to the smtp server: it is pretty easy actually. You simply open a socket to the system you find out by doing a DNS MX lookup. Then you "speak" raw SMTP protocol with the server, so `HELO`, `MAIL_FROM: ...`, `RCPT_TO: ...`. For each such statement you get a reply you can parse. After the `RCPT_TO` you are told if the message will get accepted or not. That is what you want to know. Just take a look at the SMTP documentation and have a few manual tries yourself using a simple `telnet` client.

Comment: that's actually a really bad idea, it is what spammers use to do to find valid addresses, now most mailserver will reject and mark you as a spammer. what you should do is process bounces.

Comment: also you should not be validating email addresses with regular expressions. Instead use the php validate filters http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: @arkascha don't half-open an SMTP session in order to "validate" an email address. It's unreliable at best, and considered abusive at worst. The *only* way to canonically validate an email address is to send it an email and have the user click a link to verify the address. aka [Double Opt-In](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opt-in_email#Confirmed_opt-in_.28COI.29_.2F_Double_opt-in_.28DOI.29). You've now confirmed: 1. The email address is valid. 2. It belongs to the same person as the user account on your site. 3. They actually *want* the email. 4. You're on your way to running a reputable mailer